# How can I make spartacus to use a different field configuration?

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I would like to change the endpoint to use `fields=FULL` instead of the preconfigured fields.

In particular I want to change this endpoint of the storefinder:

`https://spartacus-demo.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:8443/occ/v2/electronics-spa/stores`

Comment: Did you check the docs on this? https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/connecting-to-other-systems/#configuring-endpoints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Miroslaws comment pointed me to the official documentation and helped me to  change my stores endpoint. You can do this for all endpoints.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    B2sStorefrontModule.withConfig({
      backend: {
        occ: {
          endpoints: {
            stores: 'stores?fields=stores(FULL),pagination(DEFAULT),sorts(DEFAULT)'
          }
        }
      }
    })
  ]
})
```